# UWSim multi robots with sensors

Tags: ros, imu, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having issues setting up a scene with 2 robots, each equipped with an IMU. My scene XML looks like:

```
...
<vehicle>
    <name>AZOR</name>
    <file>data/scenes/g500ARM5.urdf</file>
    <position>
      <x> 5</x>
      <y> 7 </y>
      <z> -3 </z>
    </position>
    <orientation>
      <r>0</r>
      <p>0 </p>
      <y>0 </y>
    </orientation>
    <imu>
      <name>IMU_AZOR</name>
      <relativeTo>base_link</relativeTo>
      <position>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <z>0</z>
      </position>  
      <orientation>
        <r>0</r>
        <p>0</p>
        <y>0</y>
      </orientation>
      <std>0.00000001</std>
    </imu>
  </vehicle>

  <vehicle>
    <name>TOM</name>
    <file>data/scenes/g500ARM5.urdf</file>
    <position>
      <x> 10</x>
      <y> 8 </y>
      <z> -3 </z>
    </position>
    <orientation>
      <r>0</r>
      <p>0 </p>
      <y>0 </y>
    </orientation>
    <imu>
      <name>IMU_TOM</name>
      <relativeTo>base_link</relativeTo>
      <position>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <z>0</z>
      </position>  
      <orientation>
        <r>0</r>
        <p>0</p>
        <y>0</y>
      </orientation>
      <std>0.00000001</std>
    </imu>
  </vehicle>

  <rosInterfaces>
    <ROSOdomToPAT>
      <topic> /dataNavigator_AZOR </topic>
      <vehicleName> AZOR </vehicleName>
    </ROSOdomToPAT>
    <ROSOdomToPAT>
      <topic> /dataNavigator_TOM </topic>
      <vehicleName> TOM </vehicleName>
    </ROSOdomToPAT>
    <PATToROSOdom>
      <topic> /uwsim/odom_AZOR </topic>
      <vehicleName> AZOR </vehicleName>
    </PATToROSOdom>
    <PATToROSOdom>
      <topic> /uwsim/odom_TOM </topic>
      <vehicleName> TOM </vehicleName>
    </PATToROSOdom>
    <WorldToROSTF>
      <rootName> world </rootName>
      <enableObjects> 0 </enableObjects>
      <rate>10</rate>
    </WorldToROSTF>
    <ImuToROSImu>
      <name>IMU_AZOR</name>
      <topic>g500/IMU_AZOR</topic>
      <rate>20</rate>
    </ImuToROSImu>
    <ImuToROSImu>
      <name>IMU_TOM</name>
      <topic>g500/IMU_TOM</topic>
      <rate>20</rate>
    </ImuToROSImu>
  </rosInterfaces>
```

When I try to run this scene, UWSim gives me Segmentation Fault. However, If I remove the second IMU sensor, the simulation is working OK. How can I have two vehicles with 2 IMU sensors?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205588/uwsim-multi-robots-with-sensors/) by [raluse](https://answers.ros.org/users/21914/raluse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem comes from the WorldToROSTF element:

```
<WorldToROSTF>
  <rootName> world </rootName>
  <enableObjects> 0 </enableObjects>
  <rate>10</rate>
</WorldToROSTF>
```

After this is removed, the simulation works fine.

---

Originally posted by [raluse](https://answers.ros.org/users/21914/raluse/) with karma: 28 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2015-03-31**:
True, there was a bug on TF publishing for some sensors. I've just updated git main branch, thanks for the catch and sorry for the late response!.

**Comment by [Ragnar Moberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26108/ragnar-moberg/) on 2016-02-29**:
Do you know if your changes have made it to version 1.4? Im sitting here with the exact same issue.

ROS: Jade
UWSim 1.4
Ubuntu 14.04.4

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2016-03-01**:
Actually, it was fixed, but at some point reintroduced, Should be fixed again for indigo source, I'll merge changes to jade source right now.